# Determine if an ideal is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ and $I=(y-x^2)R+(x-4)R$ is ideal $J$ prime ?

I tried to produce such $a,b$ that $ab \in J$ but $a,b \not\in J$ but can't find so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the map
$$\theta: R\to \mathbb Z\\x\mapsto 4\\y\mapsto 16$$

Can you show that it is a homomorphism? What is its kernel?

Comment: can you show that kernel is $I$ ? i have some problems with $ker(\theta) \subset I$

Comment: The kernel will be $(y-16)R + (x-4)R$. You can show that this ideal is equal to $I$.

Comment: ok, to show this i need to show for instance that $y-x^2=(y-16)f(x,y)+(x-4)g(x,y)$ do you know what $g,f$ i should take ?

Comment: You should be able to work it out. You can find an example where $g$ is a function of $x$ alone and $f\equiv 1$.